# Installing second python on Debian

Tags: python, debian, virtualenv

So I have Debian machine for my Django production server.
I need to install second python (2.7.1) to use with virtualenv.
But it always write I don't have some modules, then I have to search manually, apt-install them and rebuild. Is there either a way to resolve the dependencies for building, or pre-compiled .deb with python 2.7.1 for Debian Squeeze?
Sorry if this is much of a noobie question, I googled, honestly.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Get the Python 2.7.1 sources and compile it manually:

```
configure --prefix=/path/to/python-2.7
make; make install
```

Comment: I'd also suggest installing various libraries before compiling: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4047583/211197
This will be helpful if it's necessary to install setuptools/pip later.

Comment: Why not `make altinstall`?

Answer (score 12):

[Python 2.7 is available for *wheezy* (testing)](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/python2.7), so you should be able to install it by adding the `testing` repository and doing some [APT pinning](http://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences#Pinning).

1) add the repository in **/etc/apt/sources.list**

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free
```

2) do the actual pinning in **/etc/apt/preferences**

```
Package: *
Pin: release n=testing
Pin-Priority: 100
```

*A `Pin-Priority` of under 500 basically means that no packages from `testing` are installed automatically, so you won't have problems with other packages.*

3) install `python2.7` from `testing`:

```
aptitude -t testing install python2.7
```

*(or `apt-get` if you don't have `aptitude`)*

Comment: This should not be done for multiple reasons. Packages from different Debian releases should not be mixed. The testing/unstable branches are working on changing the default python version to 2.7 for the Wheezy release. Squeeze is ment to use 2.6 so if you replace it with 2.7 you risk breaking everything on the system that uses python.

Comment: @Arrowmaster: I'd rather say that this is unsupported than that this should not be done. *If it breaks, you get to keep both pieces.*

Comment: Right but it's easier to just tell people that wouldn't know where to begin to fix it that it just shouldn't be done.

Comment: can you elaborate on how this would be dangerous if you are not using update-alternatives to change the default python to 2.7?  As far as I understand, python2.7 would simply exist as an additional package when pinning; it wouldn't change the default python.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: @jorelli if you're careless you might accidentally install wrong versions of libraries you already have, or something (if you fail pinning). Probably the greatest danger is in changing the default python, as you say.

Comment: I installed python 2.7 on my Debian Squeeze according to these instructions plus configuration using update-alternatives, and as Arrowmaster warned, it did break! The next apt-get update errored out with python errors; something like python is not debian_default. I switched back to python 2.6 but still had the same error?!? I eventually had to uninstall 2.7 and hack the /usr/bin/python link to get it to work again.

Comment: Same experience as @Nostradamnit. Avoid this.

Answer (score 9):

Here is two methods for Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.7 (on 18/07/2013):

## The classic

Install dependencies

```
aptitude -y install build-essential python-pip libmysqlclient-dev libadns1-dev \
 python-dev libreadline-dev libgdbm-dev zlib1g-dev libsqlite3-dev \
 libssl-dev libbz2-dev libncurses5-dev libdb-dev
```

Download python

```
cd /tmp
wget http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.5/Python-2.7.5.tar.xz
unxz -c Python*xz | tar xpf -
```

Compile

```
cd Python*
./configure  --prefix=/opt/python2.7.5 --enable-shared
make
```

Install

```
make install
echo "/opt/python2.7.5/lib" >  /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libpython2.7.conf
ldconfig
```

Test

```
/opt/python2.7.5/bin/python -c "print('Ok')"
```

Upgrade pip virtualenv

```
easy_install pip
pip -v install --upgrade distribute==0.7.3
pip -v install --upgrade virtualenv==1.9.1
```

Create an user and its virtualenv

```
adduser user_app --home /opt/user_app
su user_app
virtualenv --no-site-packages --verbose -p /opt/python2.7.5/bin/python $HOME
```

Test again

```
su user_app
cd 
source bin/activate
python -c "import sys; print sys.version"
```

## The "pythonic"

Use the package [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv#installation).

```
 pyenv install 2.7.5
```

Comment: I think I'd skip adding the custom Python install to the ld.so.conf cache. 

My approach would be to create a 'wrapper script' (/usr/local/bin/python2.7) which would : export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=opt/python2.x.x/lib and then call /opt/python-2.x.x/bin/python "$@" etc. This at least keeps everything isolated.

Answer (score 2):

Installing a chroot-environment with debootstrap could be also a fast and secure solution.
It uses about 300mb

```
debootstrap wheezy /opt/debian7
chroot /opt/debian7
apt-get install python2.7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install and switch python versions using **pythonbrew** I installed python 2.7.3 and python 2.7.9 in Debian 6 and Debian 7 and works fine.
You can follow this tutorial [pythonbrew howto](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Install_Python_2.7_or_3_on_debian_6.html)